# JQuery bind mouseenter event doesn't execute function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get a div to display on my page when I hover over an icon. The full "system" of code is a little more complicated though...

**Scenario**
On page load the user sees a small bar that displays current weather conditions for his/her area. When the user hovers over this bar, a bigger div will appear beneath it with a more detailed forecast and icons representing current weather conditions in other areas of the country.

When the user hovers over these icons, a more detailed weather forecast should appear (or as a tooltip possibly) for the area represented by the icon that was hovered over.

**Structure**
Because the HTML forwarded by Yahoo's weather api is ugly, I've written my jquery to rewrite it and output the following:

```
<div id="weather">
    <div id="weather-feed">
        <div class="weather-conditions">Mostly Cloudy, 23 C</div>
        <div class="weather-icon">
            <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"><span>Pretoria</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="weather-more-button">+</div>
    <div class="weather-extra">
        <div class="weather-forecast">
            <p style="font-size: 13pt;"><b>Forcast for your area:</b>

            </p>Thu - Mostly Clear. High: 25 Low: 14
            <br>Fri - Mostly Sunny. High: 25 Low: 17
            <br>Sat - Mostly Sunny. High: 28 Low: 18
            <br>Sun - Sunny. High: 31 Low: 17
            <br>Mon - Sunny. High: 31 Low: 17
            <br>
            <br><a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Pretoria__SF/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/SFXX0044_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>

        </div>
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="33%">
                        <img class="jhb" src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/3200.gif">
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" width="33%">
                        <img class="dbn" src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/30.gif">
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%" align="center">
                        <img class="cpt" src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/34.gif">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">JHB</td>
                    <td align="center">DBN</td>
                    <td align="center">CPT</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="jhbw">
            <hr>
            <p style="font-size: 13pt;"><b>Forcast for Johannesburg:</b>

            </p>
            <br>Thu - Mostly Clear. High: 22 Low: 11
            <br>Fri - Mostly Sunny. High: 22 Low: 14
            <br>Sat - Mostly Sunny. High: 26 Low: 15
            <br>Sun - Sunny. High: 27 Low: 14
            <br>Mon - Sunny. High: 28 Low: 13
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that all weather data shown here is dynamically generated.

**JQuery**
I've used bindings with mouseenter and mouseleave events tied to separate functions in the jquery code to facilitate the hover events:

```
var showWeather = function (target) {
    var div = $(target);
    console.clear();
    div.css("display", "block");
}
var hideWeather = function (target) {
    var div = $(target);
    div.css("display", "none");
}
$("img.jhb").bind({
    mouseenter: function () { showWeather("jhbw") },
    mouseleave: function () { hideWeather("jhbw") }
});
var showExtra = function () {
    var extra = $(".weather-extra");
    extra.css("display", "block");
}

var hideExtra = function () {
    var extra = $(".weather-extra");
    extra.css("display", "none");
}

$("#weather").bind({
    mouseenter: showExtra,
    mouseleave: hideExtra
});
```

**Problem**
Currently, only the last functions (`showExtra, hideExtra`) and the bind on `#weather` appear to work. I added in the console.clear() in the `showWeather` function so that I could see immediately via the console whether or not the function was being executed. It isn't.

I've posted a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/a3fRM/2/

I can't see what I've done wrong here. To my eye, both binds should be working in exactly the same way.

If anyone can see what's gone wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

**I realize this is probably very specific, so close the question if you must, but at least wait so that someone can answer**

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "jhbw" like target, and then using $(target).-> $("jhbw") not match with anything.

Use something like:

```
var showWeather = function (target) {
    var div = $("div ."+target);
    console.clear();
    div.css("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: Sucks that I missed that, but, having amended the code, it still isn't working :/

Comment: Well apparently there's something else wrong in my code somewhere because it still won't do anything on my page...

Comment: I have edited the code in your jsfiddle and now its working... I don't understend... something else wrong? click my link -> http://jsfiddle.net/a3fRM/3/ it works

Comment: Have you forgotten me? I care about you... and now... :)

Comment: Would the placement of my bind cause issues? The html is being rendered in the jquery, but the bind is above the part in the code where the new markup is sent to the page... I wonder if that's where my problem is